# Задача на системы счисления, код выдаёт ошибку выполнения

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, системы-счисления

Всем привет, решала задачу:

```
Ромка недавно вернулся с юбилея своего друга Сашки. Праздник 
отмечался с размахом и Ромка подумал, а что если бы юбилеи были 
чаще? Можно же не ограничиваться десятичной системой счисления. 
Ромка ввёл понятие юбилейности числа, равное максимальному 
количеству нулей в конце записи этого числа в какой-то системе 
счисления с основанием B, где B — целое число, большее единицы. 
Например, юбилейность числа 256 равна 8, так как в двоичной 
системе счисления оно оканчивается на 8 нулей. Ромка хочет узнать, 
когда его ближайший значимый юбилей, если в прошлом месяце ему 
исполнилось X лет? Значимым юбилеем он считает количество лет, 
которое обладает юбилейностью хотя бы L.

Формат входных данных
Единственная строка ввода содержит два целых числа 
X и L(1≤X≤10^12; 1≤L≤50).

Формат результата
Выведите единственное число — ответ на задачу.

Примеры
Входные данные
9990 4
Выходные данные
10000

Входные данные
100 8
Выходные данные
256

Входные данные
100 2
Выходные данные
104
```

Мой код по этой задаче:

```
X, L=map(int, input().split())
if L==1:
    print(X+1)
else:
    cnt=10**20
    maximum=int(X**(1/L))+1
    a=[1]*(maximum+1)
    a[0]=0
    a[1]=0
    i=0
    while i<=maximum:
        while not a[i]:
            i+=1
            if i>maximum:
                break
        else:
            k=i**L
            cnt=min(X-(X%k)+k, cnt)
            for j in range(i*i, maximum+1, i):
                a[j]=0
            i+=1
    print(cnt)
```

Краткое описание моего решения:

```
Ввожу входные данные, если L равно единице, то мы сразу 
можем дать ответ, это X+1, иначе мы создаём заведомо 
очень большую переменную cnt (, в которой хранится ответ, 
потом проходимся циклом while, если в какой-то момент 
i нам подходит, то заканчиваем цикл, иначе, обновляем 
cnt, вспомогательный массив (он нужен для того, чтобы 
искать ответ во вложенном while) заполняем нулями 
(то есть потенциальными ответами) в интервале от i^2 до 
maximum+1 с шагом в i, в конце программы выводим 
получившийся ответ, который лежит в cnt
```

Но проверяющая система (ACMP номер 1573) пишет, что код выдаёт ошибку выполнения на 5 тесте(скопированный вердикт: Ошибка выполнения на тесте 5), помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарна, заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Кстати, почитайте PEP8 — руководство по стилю кода на python. Ваш код сложно понять, потому что вы не соблюдаете эти правила.

Comment: Также добавьте метку python-3.

Comment: `int((5 ** 3) ** (1 / 3))` -> `4`.

Comment: отредактировала

Comment: "если L равно нулю" здесь опечаталась, уже поправила в вопросе, пробовала в случае L=1 выводить X+(X%2), но там вообще был неправильный ответ на 5 тесте, когда заменила на вывод X+1, стал неправильный ответ на 49 тесте

Comment: в таком случае, может быть не рассматривать случай L=1 как отдельный...

Comment: просто боюсь, что тогда программа будет работать слишком долго

Comment: попробовала отослать код без if L==1, там ошибка выполнения на 5 тесте

Comment: У вас есть ещё дефект вычислений, на который Stanislav указал

Comment: тогда вместо maximum = int(X**(1/L)) + 1 нужно maximum = int((X**L)**(1/L))+1?

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как этот дефект можно исправить

Comment: А что должно находить это выражение?

Comment: Что можно уже выложить решение в лоб? Не знаю по времени пройдет ли.

Comment: Мысли: если *L = 1*, ответ *X + 1*. Eсли *L = 2*, ответ в *[X + 1, X + 2^2]*. Для любого *L* ответ в *[X + 1, X + 2^L]*. Если *L* малы, можно выполнить разложение на множители небольшого количества чисел. Если *L* больше, можно перебирать *K^L*. Их мало так как *K^L <= X + 2^L*.

Comment: Я запустил ваш код на ACMP. Вердикт - "Accepted". В чём состоит вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

Отдельно обрабатываем случаи `L=1` (у вас было правильно) и `L=2`

Для `L=2` производим факторизацию чисел от `X+1` до `X+4` на простые множители - как только обнаружили, что какой-то множитель входит в разложение со степенью не меньше `2` - это число нам подходит.

Для остальных `L` перебираем `L`-е степени двойки, а потом нечётных чисел, и находим следующее за `X` кратное `B**L`, выбирая наименьшее.

Время в тестах не превышало 0.24 с для конца диапазона (`X=999999992180, L=2`)

```
 def quadraticfactors(n):
    adder = 1
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if(n%i==0):
            d = i
            c = 0
            while(n % i == 0):
                n //= i
                c += 1
                if c > 1:
                    return True
        i += adder
        if i == 3:
            adder = 2
    return False


def jub3(X, L):
    if L == 1:
        return X + 1
    if L == 2:
        for k in range(1,5):
            if quadraticfactors(X+k):
                return X + k
    jmin = 10**30
    base = 2
    while True:
        bl = base**L
        ju  = ((X + bl) // bl) * bl
        if ju - X == 1:
            return X + 1
        jmin = min(ju, jmin)
        if bl//2 > X + 1:
            break
        base += 2 if base > 2 else 1
    return jmin
```

Comment: 23 секунды для `jub(39916800, 1)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Мозг игнорировал тривиальный случай, хотя я обсуждал это с автором в неправильном ключе :) С двойкой бывают 0.7 сек времена (949413857964 2 949413857967). Может быть, стоит специально обрабатывать, а может - и так хватит. Факторизация ведь тоже O(sqrt(X))

Comment: *39916800 = 11!*. И это единственный медленный факториал для вашего кода. Остальные завершаются рано. Интересный факт.

Comment: В случае *L = 2* вы правы. Но обычно факторизация быстрее, там есть ранний выход из цикла, не надо перебирать четные делители. Константа может быть лучше.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Видимо, потому что следующее факториальное простое число уже вне диапазона 10888869450418352160768000001. А насчет факторизации - там уже сложность<=cuberoot, копейки.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вы правы насчет факторизации при L=2, ускорение велико. В общем, при малых L получается в среднем 5 мс на число

Answer (score 0):

Функция переводит из десятичного счисления в другое указанное в base,
затем подсчитываем нули

```
def convert_to(number, base):
    digits = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    if base > len(digits): return None
    result = ''
    while number > 0:
        result = digits[number % base] + result
        number //= base
    return result


n, l = input('->').split()
n = int(n) + 1
l = int(l)
for num in range(n, 1_000_000_000_000):
    for b in range(2, 36): #Системы счисления от двоичной и далее
        if '0' * l == convert_to(num, b)[-l:]:
            print(f'Получается десятичное число {num}, база системы счисления {b}, вид числа в этой системе {convert_to(num, b)}')
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

---

```
->48 1
Получается десятичное число 49, база системы счисления 7, вид числа в этой системе 100
->324 2
Получается десятичное число 325, база системы счисления 5, вид числа в этой системе 2300
```

Comment: `100, 1` -> `102`. правильный ответ `101`.

Comment: Чтобы сосчитать нули не нужно разлагать число целиком. Достаточно делить пока делится и считать.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy "правильный ответ 101" в какой системе счисления? Как число выглядит?

Comment: Хотя если нет ограничений по системе счисления с базой 101 это будет 10, т.е с одним 0 задача теряет смысл, ответ тривиальный.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
def get_primes():
    primes = [2]
    yield 2
    
    i = 3
    while True:
        for p in primes:
            if i % p == 0:
                break
            if p * p > i:
                break
        
        if i % p:
            yield i
            primes.append(i)
        i += 2
        
        
def f(X, L):
    if L == 1:
        return X + 1
    d = float("inf")
    for p in get_primes():
        d = min(p**L - (X % p**L), d)
        if p ** L > X or d == 1:
            break
    return X + d
```

Попробую объяснить его суть.

`L` нулей в конце `N` системыюе счисления, означает то, что (X + d) делится на `N**L`. Но если число делится на `N`, то оно будет делится и на его множители, поэтому я решил проверять только простые числа (оказалось хватает и простого перебора от 2 до X+2).

Далее для каждого простого, я смотрю остаток: `X % p**L`. Вычисляю `d`: `p**L - X % p**L` и беру минимум.

Получилось достаточно красиво.

Вариант без простых чисел:

```
def f(X, L):
    if L == 1:
        return X + 1
    d = float("inf")
    for n in range(2, X + 2):
        d = min(n**L - (X % n**L), d)
        if n ** L > X or d == 1:
            break
    return X + d
```

Comment: `d = 2**L - (X % 2**L)`, и в цикле шагать по нечётным. Будет быстрее чем с простыми.